# How to pick max and second max value side by side sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

[image: table]

Please refer to the image above. What I need to do is for each unique ID, pick the `ID`, `MAX(SCHEDULE_DATE)`, respective price, `Second_MAX` (`SCHEDULE_DATE`), respective price. So the output will look something like this:

[image: capture2]

Currently the query I wrote returns two records of each ID AND with same MAX_DATE in both records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         ID, x.MAX_SCHEDULE_DATE, PRICE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY SCHEDULE_DATE DESC) row_num 
     FROM 
         T_Table1 C
     INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
              MAX(SCHEDULE_DATE) MAX_SCHEDULE_DATE, ID 
          FROM 
              T_Table1 
          GROUP BY
              CADIS_ID) X ON C.ID = X.ID
    ) t
WHERE
    t.row_num <= 2
ORDER BY 
    ID, t.MAX_SCHEDULE_DATE DESC
```

Comment: You've provided good detail but in the future please put the sample data as formatted text rather than screenshots. It's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `row_number()` function to do conditional aggregation :

```
select id, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then schedule_date end) as max_schedule_date,
       max(case when seq = 1 then price end) as max_price,
       max(case when seq = 2 then schedule_date end) as second_max_schedule_date,
       max(case when seq = 2 then price end) as second_max_price
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by schedule_date desc) seq
      from table
     ) t
where seq < 3
group by id;
```

Comment: I was writing a simmillar code, but takes more ressources, and i was writing "if someone could enhance it i'll really appreciate it" then a message popped up saying there are two answers, i refreshed to find out that fullfilled my request as i was writing it XD

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write it all out, but this should give you an idea.

```
WITH id_rn AS 
  (  SELECT ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            ( PARTITION BY id 
                   ORDER BY schedule_date DESC
            ) rn
        FROM T_Table1
  )

  SELECT DISTINCT
         T1.id
         id_rn1.rn AS MAX_RN,
         id_rn2.rn AS SEC_RN
    FROM T_Table1 T1
   INNER
    JOIN id_rn 
      ON T1.id = id_rn.id
     AND id_rn.rn = 1
   INNER
    JOIN id_rn2 
      ON T1.id = id_rn2.id
     AND id_rn2.rn = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sub-query` with  `row_number()`function

```
select id, 
       max(case when rn= 1 then schedule_date end) as max_schedule_date,
       max(case when rn= 1 then price end) as max_price,
       max(case when rn= 2 then schedule_date end) as second_max_schedule_date,
       max(case when rn = 2 then price end) as second_max_price from    
    (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by Price desc) rn
          from yourtable t
    ) as Tsub where Tsub.rn in (1,2)
 group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with thetop as
(
    -- get two first top dates
    select *
    from
    (
        select *,
               ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by schedule_date desc) rownum
        from @t
    ) x
    where x.rownum <= 2
),
thetop2 as
(
    -- get data from the next row
    select *,
           LEAD(schedule_date) over
                (partition by id order by rownum) second_max_date,
           LEAD(price) over
                (partition by id order by rownum) second_max_price
    from thetop 
)
-- leave first row
select id,
       schedule_date as first_max_date,
       price as first_max_price,
       second_max_date,
       second_max_price
from thetop2
where rownum = 1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a
     AS (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SCHEDULE_DATE DESC) RN,
            ID,SCHEDULE_DATE,PRICE
     FROM T_Table1)
     SELECT * FROM a a1 LEFT JOIN A a2 ON a1.ID = a2.ID AND a2.rn = 2
     WHERE a1.rn = 1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/663c55/12)